# Favicon not working in # link url

Tags: favicon

This link does not shows any favicon. Please help me.

Link Project:
http://techpertz.com/proj/Techpertz/portfolio.php#all

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML structure, between the HEAD Tags, insert something like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="pathToYourFavicon/favicon.ico"/>
```

Hope, this helps.